# backbone.js model extends another model

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

I'm building a dashboard application with Backbone.js

There is a grid of panes called modules. Each module has its own custom data that it needs to listen to.

In this sense, I have created a backbone model called `Module` that is basically the top-level information for each module like `module_name` & `module_description`

my first inclination is to find a way to make a new special module model per module... like a "counter" module, a "messages" module, etc.

how should I approach the separate & different data per module? any design pattern recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var Module = Backbone.Model.extend({
// default properties/methods of this module
});

var MessageModule = Module.extend({
// new properties/methods of this module
});
```